# Make variable optional within a nested mixin

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have a mixin that uses a `@each` loop inside it. The `$fw-icons` variable could have up to 5 variables (3 are required). I want to make optional the 4th and 5th variables, but I'm not sure how to do some kind of if/else statement that works. If nothing is passed into the 4th or 5th variables, then the mixin breaks, so I need a way that if there is nothing that passes in, it will still work.

```
@mixin fw-dms-icons($fw-icons, $icon-color) {
  $total-number-of-icons: length($fw-icons);

  %dms-icon-default-styles {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  @each $fw-icon-item in $fw-icons {
    &.#{nth($fw-icon-item, 1)} {
      @include _dms-icon(nth($fw-icon-item, 2), $icon-color, nth($fw-icon-item, 3), nth($fw-icon-item, 4), nth($fw-icon-item, 5), $total-number-of-icons);
      @extend %dms-icon-default-styles;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be easier to give you a proper advice with the full code. (all mixins)

Comment: You can just pretend that the 4th and 5th variables are string elements.

Comment: Please provide an example of `$fw-icons` as well as the `_dms-icon` mixin.

Comment: just set `$yourVariableName: null` it will work just fine!